# iOS Fetch Data from Parse and Display

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to display data from a parse table. The class name is `Account` and the column I want to retrieve data from is called `name`. I keep getting an error of property name not found on object of type `NSArray`. I understand that you cannot pass a `NSArray` to an `NSString` but how do i display this data correctly. Any help would be great.

Here is my code that does not work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        self.test.text = objects.name;

    }];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want to do (this is just going to display 'name' for the first object in the array):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        self.test.text = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];

    }];
```